# How can I add one list to another list's field?

Tags: java, list

List

Person
name: String
age: Integer
address: List

Address
addLine1: String
addLine2: String
state: String
pincode: Integer

Comment: Just make another java class which is called address and then inherit it in your person class.

Comment: @NickGr Horrible advise. A person is NOT an address. Inheritance is meant to model relationships, it is not a shortcut to avoid code duplication. "Favour composition over inheritance" that is.

Comment: Hint: you expect other people to spend their time to help you with your request. So you please spend the time to write down a meaningful human readable question, instead of dumping something like this onto other people.

Comment: @GhostCat You are right, what I meant wasn't inheritance but ruther composition after creating the adress class. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @GhostCat I am new here it's my first time to ask a question. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This question is still a total mess.  You should **preview** questions before posting.  If you need instructions on how to do markdown formatting, there are links to read in the help center and the question's Edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you designed your models but you can follow this way:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    List<Address> addressList;

    // getter, setter, const...
}

class Address {
    // some fields...
    // getter, setter, const...
}
```

And then you can add your `address` to your `person` via `add` method:

```
    Person p = new Person();
    Address a = new Address();
    // modiy person and address...
     
    p.getAddressList().add(a);
```